# Sort list of strings using lambda and with multiple conditions in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of strings and **I want to sort the resulting list by string length. Strings with equal length should be sorted by how often the letter ’A’ occurs in them, so that the ones with the largest number of As come first and the others next**. I have tried using lambda function to sort but its not working

```
result = sorted(result, key=len)
or
result.sort(lambda x,y: cmp(len(x), len(y)))
```

This is perfectly sorting based on the length of the string, but I have another condition to sort on number of As if the length is equal, how can I achieve this?

I have tried the following and yet was not able to figure it out

```
  result.sort(key = (lambda x,y: 1 if len(x)>len(y) else (-1 if len(x)<len(y) else (1 if x.count("A")>y.count("A") else -1))))


 result = sorted(result, lambda x,y: 1 if len(x)>len(y) else (-1 if len(x)<len(y) else (1 if x.count("A")>y.count("A") else -1)))
```

I have tried both sort and sorted and I always get an error
`sort() takes no positional arguments`
if I don't specify key= Infront of lambda and `sorted expected 1 arguments, got 2`

Comment: python sorting is stable, so when you need to sort by A then by B then by C, you can always do `x.sort(C); x.sort(B); x.sort(A)`. No need to shoehorn everything in one single lambda.

Comment: its not actually sort on a single character, the condition is to sort on length then if the length of both the strings are equal then the string having more As should come first

Comment: in the above comment, A, B, C are conditions (lambdas), not characters

Comment: "lambda x,y: cmp(len(x), len(y))" python removed comparator functions in P3, current python uses a key function, you just return what to compare the objects by rather than perform the result of the comparison yourself. You should stop using Python 2 documentation.

Comment: Incidentally "it's not working" is about as unhelpful as can be, readers figure out things are not working because you're asking a function. *How* is it not working is a lot more useful (error messages, expected v observed results, ...)

Comment: Sorry if the question is not properly formatted, I will edit it now, I have mentioned the errors at the last line as you have mentioned I was referring to old documentation, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
a = ["AAd", "aAAd", "AAAd", "adAA"]
a.sort(key=lambda x: (len(x), -x.count('A')))
# output
[ 'AAd', 'AAAd', 'aAAd', 'adAA']
```

We are firstly sorting based on the length if length is equal then sort based on `-x.count('A')` so if we have 3 elements then we do counting of A in them, lets say counting is [3, 2, 1] so if we arrange them in ascending order we will get [1,2,3] but we need [3,2,1] so we appended negative sign in them like this [-3, -2, -1].

Comment: Sorry If I was not clear, I only want to sort based on count if the length of both the string are equal so in your example I want
[ 'AAd', 'AAAd', 'aAAd', 'adAA']

Comment: Got your point, I updated the answer now check

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. I might be asking a simple question but could you please explain what does -x.count('A') means here, I know the count function for a string but I couldn't figure out why adding -x is working.

Comment: Let me add the explanation in the answer.

Comment: ahh got it, another stupid question,  but how is it picking up the count condition only if the length of the strings are same? we didn't mention it anywhere right, I am in the assumption that it will check both the conditions on every iteration.

Comment: Yes it is checking both the condition but first condition is length and if the length is matching then it will check other conditon, so if two strings have different length then there is no need to check the count of A in them and if they have same length then we will check the count of A.